# Block scroll when Lightbox appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

I use [DOM window](http://swip.codylindley.com/DOMWindowDemo.html) script for Lightboxes on my website. Is there any way to block scroll on main page when Lightbox appears and unblock when it disappears?

Or, maybe, you can advice better Lightbox script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

User this to disable or enable window scrollbar :

```
document.body.style.overflow="hidden";
```

on show your lightbox and

```
document.body.style.overflow="visible";
```

on hiding your lightbox.

but if your are really looking for a better lightbox library you can try this jQuery plugin :

[jQuery Lightbox Plugin](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)

Comment: Thanks for your help!
jQuery Lightbox Plugin is for images, but I need to use text.

Comment: the best solution for you is to use jquery windows, witch jquery lightbox plugin uses it. 
you should just use floating window of jquery to render anything you want in it.