# css for remove scroll bar for lightbox contact form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi this is my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example4/colorbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test").click(function () { //on clicking the link above
        $(this).colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>External Form</h3>
<a href="https://dev88.wufoo.com/forms/ze7xusq0j2tum9/" id="test">Please fill out my form.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine, like as lightbox pop-up . Now i need when the form display, the scroll bar should be remove, How it possible with my code?

Please help me?

Comment: increase the width and/or height of the iframe....

Comment: do you have live site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Colorbox Lightbox - Remove Vertical Scrollbar of an IFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056765/colorbox-lightbox-remove-vertical-scrollbar-of-an-iframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

Set `overflow: hidden;` on the body tag like this:

> ```
> <style type="text/css"> 
>     body {
>         overflow:hidden; 
>     } 
> </style>
> ```

Comment: maybe something like this then `$(this).colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%", "overflow-y": "hidden"});` hiding vertical scroll bar (y)

Comment: create a jsfiddle please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037674/colorbox-scrollbars - possible solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527663/block-scroll-when-lightbox-appears -> there seems to be quite a few solutions out there. Just search and try one or two.