# Colorbox Lightbox - Remove Vertical Scrollbar of an IFrame

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, colorbox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example4/colorbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test").click(function () { //on clicking the link above
        $(this).colorbox({iframe:true, width:"90%", height:"100%"});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>External Form</h3>
<a href="https://dev88.wufoo.com/forms/ze7xusq0j2tum9/" id="test">Please fill out my form.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine now, but i need remove scrollbar in this code, how to remove vertical scrollbar of iframe?

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test").click(function () { //on clicking the link above
        $(this).colorbox({iframe:true, width:"90%", height:"100%", scrolling: false});
    });
});
```

Comment: Still i have an doubt, form didn't display fully,

Comment: @user3890317: It might be because your container is too small to display all the content, and you have disabled scrolling. Resize your `iframe` using CSS or jQuery properties.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do what you're after by adding `scrolling:false`, according to the documentation: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/.

Therefore:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test").click(function () { //on clicking the link above
        $(this).colorbox({iframe:true, width:"90%", height:"100%", scrolling: false});
    });
});
```

Or if the above doesn't work for some unknown reason, try adding the below CSS code to your `<head>` element.

```
<style type="text/css">

    iframe {

        overflow: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;

    }

</style>
```

You can also create a separate CSS file and apply the style there.

Answer (score 0):

Add **scrolling: false**

```
$.colorbox({
    inline:true, 
    width:'95%',
    scrolling: false // *********
});
```